# Published page contains <tcdl:ComponentPresentation>

Tags: web8, componentpresentation, dynamic-publishing, component

I have been migrated to SDL Web 8.1. I have published one Page. The main body  of page content is having

```xml
<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="dynamic" ComponentURI="value" TemplateURI="value">
```

When I browse my page and the main content is missing.
Earlier my page used to published as

```xml
<tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="value" ComponentURI="value" TemplateURI="value">
```

Can anyone help me if I'm missing any jar/configurations?

## update

I have set TCDL engine in the Deployer configuration file as below:

```xml
<TCDLEngine>
    <Properties>          
        <Property Name="tcdl.dotnet.style" Value="controls"/>
        <Property Name="tcdl.jsp.style" Value="tags"/> 
        <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel" />
    </Properties>       
   <!--<TagBundle Resource="webforms_tcdl.xml" />-->
</TCDLEngine>
```

Am I missing anything here? Else suggest or direct me what have to be set?

Comment: Can you check your deployer conf? The target language configuration is now defined in this file.

Comment: @NunoLinhares Thanks, I updated my question with more information.

Answer (score 4):

In your deployer Role, try updating the value to dotnet in following property
`<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="dotnet" />` in the cd_deployer_conf.xml file

Restart the deployer services and unpublish the page once and publish it again to see whether it helps to generate the tags`<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="dynamic" ComponentURI="value" TemplateURI="value">`

Comment: Might be useful if you **edit** your answer and provide the file in which this needs to be changed, that might not be clear to everybody reading your answer.

Comment: Thanks Bart, I have updated the answer with additional details now